# Optimizar consulta Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo el siguiente escenario.

Conectado a una db Oracle con Sql Developer una consulta Pivot tarda en ejecutarse 1.5 sec esa misma consulta adaptada para SQL Server vinculando el servidor db Oracle tarda en ejecutarse 34 a 36 minutos, y estamos hablando de que el origen es el mismo, mismas tablas mismos datos, misma consulta adaptada para SQL Server, la unica diferencia es que el Servidor esta vinculado. Ese podria ser el problema?

He probado de igual forma con Access conectandome via ODBC y tarda poco menos de 20 sec en ejecutarse la misma consulta, no entiendo cual es el problema, si pudiera ayudarme a optimizar esta consulta se los agradeceria.

Este es el SQL:

```
SELECT  * FROM 
(Select 
d.comp_part_nbr,
    SUM(a.h_volume *d.occurs) seatVol,  
    sum(case a.r_plant when 'G VII)' then a.h_volume *d.occurs else 0 end) as "G",
    sum(case a.r_plant when 'D I)' then a.h_volume *d.occurs else 0 end) as "DI",
    sum(case a.r_plant when 'D II)' then a.h_volume *d.occurs else 0 end) as "DII",
    sum(case a.r_plant when 'F I' then a.h_volume *d.occurs else 0 end) as "FI",
    sum(case a.r_plant when 'F II' then a.h_volume *d.occurs else 0 end) as "FII",
    sum(case a.r_plant when 'F III' then a.h_volume *d.occurs else 0 end) as "FIII"
FROM 
[LINK_CONEX]..[RPTDBA].[TW] A
INNER JOIN [LINK_CONEX]..[RPTDBA].[TZ] D
ON
a.part_nbr = d.part_nbr
AND
a.mfg_plant_id = D.mfg_plant_id
INNER JOIN [LINK_CONEX]..[RPTDBA].[TA] E
ON
d.comp_part_nbr = E.comp_part_nbr
AND
D.mfg_plant_id = E.mfg_plant_id
WHERE e.cat_1_cd = 'Seat'
GROUP BY ROLLUP( d.comp_part_nbr)) s
where comp_part_nbr is not null
order by seatVol desc;
```

DS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varios problemas que pueden estar pasando aquí y ninguno excluye al otro.

1. Los drivers que se usan para conectarse de SQL Server a Oracle son muy lentos.
2. El tráfico de red no es óptimo.
3. Para poder hacer la consulta es necesario traer toda la información de las tablas de Oracle a la memoria de la instancia de SQL Server.

Para solucionar el tercer problema, que puede ser el principal, sería mejor usar OPENQUERY para que la consulta se ejecute en Oracle y solo regrese el resultado.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ( [LINK_CONEX], N'
SELECT  
    d.comp_part_nbr,
    SUM(a.h_volume *d.occurs) seatVol,  
    sum(case a.r_plant when ''G VII)'' then a.h_volume *d.occurs else 0 end) as "G",
    sum(case a.r_plant when ''D I)''   then a.h_volume *d.occurs else 0 end) as "DI",
    sum(case a.r_plant when ''D II)''  then a.h_volume *d.occurs else 0 end) as "DII",
    sum(case a.r_plant when ''F I''    then a.h_volume *d.occurs else 0 end) as "FI",
    sum(case a.r_plant when ''F II''   then a.h_volume *d.occurs else 0 end) as "FII",
    sum(case a.r_plant when ''F III''  then a.h_volume *d.occurs else 0 end) as "FIII"
FROM RPTDBA.TW A
INNER JOIN RPTDBA.TZ D ON a.part_nbr = d.part_nbr
                          AND a.mfg_plant_id = D.mfg_plant_id
INNER JOIN RPTDBA.TA E ON d.comp_part_nbr = E.comp_part_nbr
                          AND D.mfg_plant_id = E.mfg_plant_id
WHERE e.cat_1_cd = ''Seat''
GROUP BY d.comp_part_nbr
order by seatVol desc;');
```

Comment: He adaptado tu codigo SQL pero me esta arrojando el siguiente error:
"LINK_CONEX" returned message "ORA-00903: invalid table name"
He revisado el script detenidamente y todo esta ok. Podria ser que la sentencia sea diferente para tablas o vistas o se tratan de igual forma?
@Luis Cazares

Comment: Olvidaba que Oracle no usa corchetes. Quítalos de los nombres de las tablas y BD.

Comment: Tambien hacia falta eliminar el punto y coma despues del Oder By.
Ha funcionado a la perfeccion tardando solo 3 segundos en ejecutar la consulta.
Gracias se puede cerrar el tema.
@Luis Cazares